Why do these identical materials look different?
I have two materials: M_Compass and M_Compass_Glass. I copied and pasted all nodes from M_Compass_Glass into M_Compass, so they should be identical. This image shows where each material is applied. The highlighted faces are M_Compass_Glass while the rest are M_Compass.


However, if I try to use the same material across the entire mesh, it doesn't work. If I use M_Compass, the glass becomes opaque:

If I use M_Compass_Glass, parts of the compass become transparent when viewed from certain angles:

How can this be possible when both materials contain the exact same nodes?

A material's appearance is not only dependent on the shader nodes, but also on the settings in the Material Properties to the right of your screenshot (especially when you are using EEVEE), but I cannot see them so I cannot spot if there is a difference. They will not be copied with the nodes and therefore not be the same unless they are left at default (which I doubt when seeing the transparent material) or when you duplicate the complete the material.

And another caveat: when you are using Cycles for rendering, the settings there will be the Cycles settings and they might be the same, but the Material Preview uses EEVEE and those settings you can only see after switching the render engine to EEVEE so they could still be different between those materials.
